# Printing out a list with bullet points after user input (chatbot problem)

Tags: python-3.x, chatbot

I am trying to build a simple coffee shop chatbot. It first asks which drink you'd like and then if you would like another drink. At the end of the script, if you have chosen 3 drinks, I want the program to print the list of drinks in bullet points preceded by "print('Okay, so I have:').

This is the utils .py doc:

```
def print_message():
    print('I\'m sorry, I did not understand your selection. Please enter the corresponding letter for your response.')

def get_size():
    res = input('What size drink can I get for you? \n[a] Small \n[b] Medium \n[c] Large \n> ')

    if res == 'a':
        return 'small'
    elif res == 'b':
        return 'medium'
    elif res == 'c':
        return 'large'
    else:
        print_message()
        return get_size()
def order_latte():
    res = input('And what kind of milk for your latte? \n[a] 2% milk \n[b] Non-fat milk \n[c] Soy milk \n> ')

    if res == 'a':
        return 'latte'
    elif res == 'b':
        return 'non-fat latte'
    elif res == 'c':
        return 'soy latte'
    else:
        print_message()
        return order_latte()
```

And this is the main code for the chatbot:

```
from utils import print_message, get_size, order_latte


def coffee_bot():
    print('Welcome to the cafe!')
    order_drink = 'y'
    drinks = []

    while order_drink == 'y':
        size = get_size()
        drink_type = get_drink_type()
        drink = f'{size} {drink_type}'
        print(f'Alright, that\'s a {drink}!')

        while True:
            order_drink = input('Would you like to order another drink? (y/n) \n> ')
            if order_drink in ['y', 'n']:
                break

        print('Okay, so I have:')
        for drink in drinks:
            print('-', drink)

    name = input('Can I get your name please? \n> ')
    print(f'Thanks, {name}! Your order will be ready shortly.')


def get_drink_type():
    res = input('What type of drink would you like? \n[a] Brewed Coffee \n[b] Mocha \n[c] Latte \n> ')

    if res == 'a':
        return 'brewed coffee'
    elif res == 'b':
        return order_mocha()
    elif res == 'c':
        return order_latte()
    else:
        print_message()
        return get_drink_type()


# Define new functions here!

def order_mocha():
    while True:
        res = input(
            'Would you like to try our limited-edition peppermint mocha? \n[a] Sure! \n[b] Maybe next time! \n> ')

        if res == 'a':
            return 'peppermint mocha'
        elif res == 'b':
            return 'mocha'

        print_message()


coffee_bot()
```

Does anyone have suggestions on how to solve this and perhaps improve the code?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: you never add any drinks to the `drinks` to the list. before asking if they want to order another drink append the current drink to the drinks lis.

Answer (score 0):

You are not appending to your list, you need to do so every call:

```
def coffee_bot():
    print('Welcome to the cafe!')
    order_drink = 'y'
    drinks = []

    while order_drink == 'y':
        size = get_size()
        drink_type = get_drink_type()
        drink = f'{size} {drink_type}'
        drinks.append(size) # added
        drinks.append(drink_type) # added

        print(f'Alright, that\'s a {drink}!')

        while True:
            order_drink = input('Would you like to order another drink? (y/n) \n> ')
            if order_drink in ['y', 'n']:
                break

        print('Okay, so I have:')
        for drink in drinks:
            print('-', drink)

    name = input('Can I get your name please? \n> ')
    print(f'Thanks, {name}! Your order will be ready shortly.')
```

output:

```
Okay, so I have:
- small
- brewed coffee
- small
- brewed coffee
- large
- latte
```

Comment: Thanks! But actually what I meant is to have have a final output like this:

Okay, so I have:
- small non-fat latte
- large mocha
- medium brewed coffee
- ...

Comment: change your for loop to this `print(' - '.join([i for i in drinks]))` I think that's what you want?

Comment: Not really. I would like to have bullet points with each row containing the chosen coffee. For example, 1. small non-fat latte 2. large mocha 3. medium brewed coffee